# python find the minimum number of coins

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am tasked to make a program that will take a monetary amount and find the minimum number of coins needed to get that amount. here is my code.

```
import math

n1 = eval(input("Enter a monetary amount: "))

n1 = n1 * 100

dollars = 0
quarters = 0
dimes = 0
nickels = 0
pennies = 0

dollars = n1 / 100
n1 %= 100

quarters = n1 / 25 
n1 %= 25

dimes = n1 / 10 
n1 %= 10

nickels = n1 / 5 
n1 %= 5

pennies = n1


print (int(dollars), int(quarters), int(dimes), int(nickels), int(pennies))
```

whenever I enter a number that needs nickels, it doesn't count them. for example, the output for 1.05 would be

```
1 0 0 0 0
```

the output for 1.15 is

```
1 0 1 0 4
```

any hints would be appreciated, thanks.

edited a typo that i had, code is still not working as intended though.

Comment: Writing a solution that works on any monetary system is tricky, if you have values like 10, 7, 5 and 1. If you want to get the best configuration for 12, you can't just use the biggest one and carry on, because that would yield a result of `1*10 2*1` using 3 coins, although you can do it with 2: `1*7 1*5`. I'll try to write such a solution anyways, *because* it is tricky.

Comment: Why use `eval` instead of `int` or `float` ?

Comment: @KevinMGranger I'd assume it passed through the `2to3` script as it changes python2's `input(...)` to `eval(input(..))`

Comment: I can't reproduce that behaviour, can you add `print(repr(n1))` in between each step? I have a feeling float operations are responsible for this.

Comment: its giving me 14.999... and so on instead of 15, 5, etc. im not sure why or how to fix it

Comment: yep, floats operations are to blame, I'd recommend switching out `eval` for `decimal.Decimal` and seeing if that solves your problem, either that or get the user to input the number in cents and skip the `n1 * 100` step, or using `round`

Comment: decimal.Decimal worked. thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a typo: `nickels` vs `nickles`

Edit: now that you've fixed the typo, it looks like it's definitely a rounding issue.  Since you're converting from dollars to a whole number of cents, try turning it into an integer before doing any operations.

Change your `n1 = n1 * 100` line to `n1 = int(round(n1 * 100))`.  I tried this out on my computer and it seemed to work.

Comment: thanks, but its still not giving me the correct number of coins

Answer (score 1):

You're running into a floating point issues:

```
>>>> 1.15*100
114.99999999999999
```

As you can see, here you clearly do not have 115 cents. You have *just* under that. So you use one dollar, one dime, and 4.99999 pennies (`int` rounds it down to four).

The easiest way to fix it is to have the user give you an integer number of cents so that you can work in cents the entire time, or to use the built-in `round` function to get rid of floating point errors.

Comment: I agree with Rob. For completeness, when you need to deal with more involved processing on decimals, including currency, check out the  decimal library: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/decimal.html

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for a more comprehensive explanation on what is going on but basically when you type `1.05` into your code (or through an `eval`) it does not store the exact value you might expect:

```
>>> (1.05).as_integer_ratio()
(4728779608739021, 4503599627370496)
```

If you want the computer to store the exact decimal representation of the number you can simply use [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html?highlight=decimal.decimal#decimal.Decimal) for the intermediate step:

```
n1 = decimal.Decimal(input("Enter a monetary amount: "))

n1 = int(n1 * 100) #now you won't get rounding issues
```

alternately you can parse the number entered yourself to remove the decimal and skip the math required to compensate all togther:

```
def dollar_to_cent(s):
    n,_,end = s.partition(".")
    if not all(i=="0" for i in end[2:]):
        raise ValueError("can only have up to two digits after decimal.")
    return int("{}{:0<2}".format(n,end[:2]))

>>> dollar_to_cent("1")
100
>>> dollar_to_cent("2.")
200
>>> dollar_to_cent("2.3")
230
>>> dollar_to_cent("2.05")
205
>>> dollar_to_cent("2.050000")
205
>>> dollar_to_cent("2.001")
Traceback (most recent call last):
   ...
ValueError: can only have up to two digits after decimal.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is best to work with cents all the way for these kind of problems. Try to make 105 cents (integer) instead of 1.05 times 100. You can avoid rounding all together. Further, since you care about "remainder", use modulo operator instead of division.

I'd solve it like this:

```
cents = 115
remainder = cents%25
nickels = (cents - remainder)/25

cents = remainder
remainder = cents%10
dimes = (cents - remainder)/10

...
```

and so on.

However, probably not the question you asked but in general cases this problem is NP-hard, and further depending on the coin denominations some change is not makeable.

Comment: `n1 %= 100` OP *is* using the modulo operator.

Comment: True; sorry about the wording; I meant use "division" after "modulo" to avoid floating points. to be sure about divisibility, and don't do the first multiplication n1*100.